# Fetching HTML data from Sql Server in xml format

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, gridview

I have to display user reviews in my asp.net Web page. I have taken another gridview inside review grid.

e.g.

Review

User Name                                      Review Categories(Coming in XML Format)
Review
1                     Relationship             M

1 review can have many review categories.

I want data from database in single call, so i am generating xml for review categories

```
SELECT    
U.UserName,
CCR.ReviewDesc,
CCR.ReviewDate,
(select CL.CodeDesc AS 'Category',CCRD.Rating as 'Rating' from CollegeCourseReviewDetails CCRD, CodeLookup CL

WHERE CCRD.ReviewId=CCR.ReviewId AND CCRD.ReviewCategoryId = CL.CodeId
FOR XML PATH)  as List
From Users U INNER JOIN Review CCR ON U.UserId = CCR.UserId

END
```

Code is working perfectly but it is encoding html, eg to give bold effect i am using `<b>`, that is not giving bold effect in my gridview but printing as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the gridview's rowdatabound event to debug the code and make sure the text is being html encoded at some point.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

If that's the case, you could decode text within the same event handler. Something like:

```
Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells(3).Text)
    End If
End Sub
```